# STM32L1 Stop mode GPIO setup

Tags: stm32, low-power

in my project where I use stop mode, I would like to configure 4 ways to wakeup.
On four gpio I have an EXTI (two of them only increment the variable), two of them change the state of the variable to the opposite (buttons). Stop mode gives a low level power consumption several uA. Only when I have all GPIO disabled, even used.
My function to enter to low power mode below:

```
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};
    /* Configure all GPIO port pins in Analog Input mode (floating input trigger OFF) */
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_All;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_ANALOG;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOH, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    /* Disable GPIOs clock */
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_DISABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_DISABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_DISABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOH_CLK_DISABLE();
    
    HAL_SuspendTick();                  /* To Avoid timer wake-up. */
    HAL_PWR_EnableSleepOnExit();
    HAL_PWR_EnterSTOPMode(PWR_LOWPOWERREGULATOR_ON,PWR_STOPENTRY_WFI);
```

How should I configure the GPIO, to get low current and be able to use gpio interrupts at the same time

````
void HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback(uint16_t GPIO_Pin){
    SystemClock_Config();
    HAL_ResumeTick();
    HAL_PWR_DisableSleepOnExit();
    if(GPIO_Pin == Input1Pin) {
        input1++;
    }
    else if(GPIO_Pin == Input2Pin) {
        input2++;
    }
    else if(GPIO_Pin == SW1_Pin){
        activeInput=1;
        //displayValue(activeInput,1);
    }
    else if(GPIO_Pin == SW2_Pin){
        activeInput=2;
        //displayValue(activeInput,1);
    }
    else {
        __NOP ();
    }
}
```
````